# Can I use stat to show human readable size of file?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use stat command to display a list of files in the current directory, sorted by largest  to smallest. 
my script is

```
filelist=$(ls -p | grep -v/)
filesize=$(stat -c "%s : %n" $filelist | sort -nr)
```

It works however it displays the size in bytes. Is there a way to show it in a human readable format using stat? or do i have to try something else. thank you for the help.

Comment: Why not just use `ls -hlS`?

Comment: Or `ls -1shS` if you just want the size and filename

Comment: @Aaron I thought that too, but `ls -s` shows block size, not real size.

Comment: @wjandrea ah damn, that's what happens when you read the man too quickly and don't test. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Best practice is to [not parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [quote variables](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086), which would require redesigning the script. One way is to use a glob to make an array (like `all_files=(*)`), filter out the directories, and go from there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know, the `stat` program cannot display human readable sizes by itself. But you can always pipe it to another program that does it, such as `numfmt`:

```sh
stat -c %s /path/to/file | numfmt --to=iec
```

Applied to your example, it would be:

```sh
filelist=$(ls -p | grep -v/)
filesize=$(
    stat -c "%s %n" $filelist | sort -nr -k1 | while read filesize filename; do
        printf '%s : %s\n' "$(numfmt --to=iec <<< $filesize)" "$filename"
    done
)
```

Please note I added the `-k1` option when calling `sort` because I assume you want to sort using the size, not the name.

`numfmt` has the advantage that you can choose how to want to display the human readable size. I suggested `--to=iec` because this is the most common for file sizes, but you may want to use other conversions. Please refer to the [numfmt man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html#EXAMPLES).

As a last note, I would advise you against storing files directly out of the `$()` capture because it will not work when a filename contains a space character. You could use `find` to list the files and get the size at the same time, e.g.:

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -printf '%s %f\n' |
    sort -nr -k1 |
    while read filesize filename
do
    printf '%s : %s\n' "$(numfmt --to=iec <<< $filesize)" "$filename"
done
```

Comment: The answer's current usage of `while read` isn't all that safe with arbitrary filenames either -- try names with backslashes, or worse, ones with newlines. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s %f\0' | sort -znr | while IFS= read -r -d ' ' filesize && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do ...` should work, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That’s right but backslashes and newlines are incredibly rare among filenames so I tend not to take them into account for educational purposes.

Comment: Thing is, it takes only one low-probability event to really ruin your month -- the one I was present for was a case where a Python library used a C module with a buffer overflow that dumped random memory into a string that was later used to form a filename. Sure, that was an "incredibly rare" event, but a poorly-written script processing files that tool created then proceeded to delete my employer-of-the-time's entire collection of backups used to support customer billing.

Comment: Moral of that story: **Better to educate folks on how to follow practices that don't have subtle failure modes**, and then you (and the people consuming those lessons) don't need to worry about whether those modes are reachable in any given case.

Comment: (And the above random-buffer-overwrite case is only one; you've also got to worry about folks escalating privilege escalation or lateral-movement attacks intentionally creating hostile names because they want to insert `/etc/shadow` into a backup that they can then read, if the backup-processing code has more privileges than they do. A good sysadmin on the red team figuring out how to break into your systems can get crafty at times).

Comment: (BTW, beyond backslashes and newlines -- also try names that start or end with whitespace).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Files starting or ending with a space character are also extremely rare because many software will trim them, e.g. Windows Explorer, and if a software willingly creates files like that, you’d better ask the software programmer to fix it rather than the people who write script to deal with such filenames.

Comment: But IMO the real issue is that if we want to deal with such filenames in SO answers, the extra code usually shifts the answer off-topic.

Comment: I really don't agree with that -- if your answer isn't robust against all possible inputs (or, at minimum, explicit about its requirements and failure modes), *it's simply not a correct answer*. Anyhow, maybe this needs to be moved to meta.

Comment: And then the OP might ask questions like "why do you use a `-z` option" which is an interesting question but totally unrelated to the reason he came here for.

Comment: Definitely true; I often do end up answering those follow-on questions in comments myself. That's part of teaching best practices -- making sure people understand the "why".  Bigger picture: yes, writing correct code in bash requires a lot of ceremony to work around historical design misfeatures; but to not demonstrate that ceremony means one is demonstrating buggy practices, encouraging code with those practices to find its way into production.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207853/discussion-between-vdavid-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 3):

But ls can do that:

```
ls --human-readable --kibibytes -Sl
```

If you don't want a full ls output can use it with du:

```
for FILE in `ls -S`; do du -sh $FILE ; done
```

Comment: NOTE: `du` show disk usage size, which larger than `ls` and `stat` tell size